# Why does being timed out of reviewing edits preempt me from editing a question that has pending edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

I've used up my 20 "review pending edits" for the day.

I see an error that I'd like to fix -- which I can do without review -- but there is a pending edit on the question.  The engine locks me out from editing that question, telling me I've used up my edit reviews for the day.

I can still edit to my heart's content on other questions without pending edits, though.

Bug?  By design?

**EDIT:**  I clicked on the Edit link from the main question's page.  I did not run across this question in the review queue.  I didn't see an "Improve" link at all, but I might have missed it.

Comment: I *think* you can still click "improve" to bypass the review limit.

Comment: Thanks Anna.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Hrm. Maybe I'm wrong then. Clicking "edit" on a question with a pending suggested edit should bring up an overlay that looks basically the same as what you'd see in the review queue.

Comment: Yes, that's what happened, and I couldn't do anything with that question.  (Which was frustrating, because someone had rejected exactly the edit I was going to make as "too minor."  Grrrr ... :) )